# Multiplication of two ergodic and stationary processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

If X and Y are stationary and ergodic processes, then, is XY a stationary and ergodic process?
I think the answer is true, but I do not know how to find the mean (we do not know Y and X are independent of each other).
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no to both questions, here are counterexamples. Take for $X$ a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli ($\pm 1$) random variables and take for $Z$ an independent sequence. To construct a counterexample to the first claim ($XY$ is stationary), set $Y_n=X_n$ for $n$ even and $Y_n=Z_n$ for $n$ odd. Then $Y$ by itself is again just i.i.d. Bernoulli, but $XY$ is equal to an i.i.d. Bernoulli sequence on odd indices and identically equal to $1$ on even indices, so that it is not stationary.

Even if $XY$ is stationary, it need not be ergodic. For that, take $X$ as before and let $\xi$ be another Bernoulli random variable that is independent of $X$ and set $Y = \xi X$. Then obviously $Y$ equal to $X$ in law, but $XY$ is identically equal to $1$ with probability $1/2$ and identically equal to $-1$ with probability $1/2$, so that it is stationary but not ergodic.

Comment: but please look at the book (Asymptotic theory for econometricians by Halbert white proposition 3.35 page 45) it says : If $\{(Z_t,X_t,Y_t)\}$ is a stationary ergodic sequence, then $\{X_tX'_t\}$, $\{X_tY_t\}$, $\{Z_tX_t\}$, $\{Y_tY'_t\}$, $\{Z_tY_t\}$, and $\{Z_tZ'_t\}$ are stationary ergodic sequences.

Comment: There is a difference between the pair $(X,Y)$ being a stationary ergodic sequence and $X$ and $Y$ each separately being a stationary ergodic sequence. Your question appeared to be for the latter but the reference you quote is for the former.

Comment: But what is the difference, we can decompose a joint process to separate processes, is not it?

Comment: Look at my first example: $X$ and $Y$ taken separately are stationary, but the pair $(X,Y)$ is not.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question, it might seem easy but for me is difficult. If ${x_t,y_t}$ are joint stationary. then is $x_{t-a}y_t$ stationary for all $a$?

Comment: $Y_n$ in your example are independent but not identically distributed. Clearly $Y_n$ does not have the same law as $Y_{n+1} $

Comment: @Dexter, is it still unclear after my typofix? I guess you are talking about the first example.

Comment: I guess the statement should include $X_nY_n$ is nondegenerate for all n

Comment: @MartinHairer In the second case, in what sense do you say that XY is not ergodic? I've plotted the sample means several times and they tend to the same place.

Comment: $\xi$ is a single RV, not an iid sequence…